# What is $\left( \boldsymbol{e} \, \cdot \, \boldsymbol{\nabla} \right) \left( \boldsymbol{a} \times \boldsymbol{b} \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, cross-product

I am interested in determining the following:
$$
\left( \boldsymbol{e} \, \cdot \, \boldsymbol{\nabla}  \right)
\left( \boldsymbol{a} \times \boldsymbol{b} \right) \, ,
$$
where $\boldsymbol{a}$, $\boldsymbol{b}$, and $\boldsymbol{e}$ are vector fields.

Can the product rule be applied here?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Is $e$ a vector field or a constant vector?

Comment: @timur: does it matter?

Comment: @timur Yes, $\boldsymbol{e}$ is a vector field.

Comment: Product rule applies

Comment: @timur Yes you are right. i swapped out the signs in my previous calculations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\vec{x}_i$ denote the $i$th element of a right-handed orthogonal basis, so$$(e\cdot\nabla)(a\times b)=(e_i\partial_i)(\epsilon_{jkl}a_kb_l\vec{x}_j)$$
$$=e_i\epsilon_{jkl}(\partial_ia_kb_l+a_k\partial_ib_l)\vec{x}_j$$
$$=[(e\cdot\nabla)a]\times b+a\times[(e\cdot\nabla)]b.$$